Power Query: how can i parse list of : seperated list of key:values
I want to parse list like this in power query
        name: david
 spouse name: rachel 
        kids: 3
        
        name: ronald
 spouse name: dilda
        kids: 2 

Result should be:
name    spouse name kids
-----   ----------- ----
david   rachel      3
ronald  dilda       2

Thanks !

Your sample data is not clear with regards row, columns and cells.

The input is in text file with the above structure.

The input is as described above in a text file. There is empty line between records. Each record in the above example have 3 fields.

Basically, what you want to do is

split the text by blank line so you have a list of text entries that should be converted to records,
convert each such text entry into a record, then
turn the records into a table.

fTextEntryToRecord
First, create a function query called "fTextEntryToRecord" that, given a block of text to convert into a record, will return a record. It might look something like this:
//* If this doesn't work, you can turn it into a normal, debuggable query by changing this line's double-slash to a single slash
(TextEntry as text) as nullable record =>
let
/*/
let
  TextEntry = "       name: david#(lf)" &
              "spouse name: rachel#(lf)" &
              "       kids: 2",
//*/
  Lines = Lines.FromText(TextEntry),
  #"Converted To Record" = List.Accumulate(
    Lines, // process each line
    [], // start with an empty record
    (r, line) => // Function that, given a record and a line of text, adds a field to the record
      let
        FieldValue = Text.Split(line, ": "), // this assumes you'll never have a colon in your data, but I'm sure you can take it from here if this isn't the case.
        Field = Text.Trim(FieldValue{0}),
        Value = Text.Trim(FieldValue{1}),
        #"Added Field" = if (List.Count(FieldValue) = 2) then
          Record.AddField(r, Field, Value)
        else
          r // Note, Power-Query is extremely lazy (i.e. efficient). If FieldValue isn't split into exactly 2 then Field and Value aren't even calculated. 
      in
        #"Added Field"
  ),
  ReturnValue = if (Record.FieldCount(#"Converted To Record") = 0) then
    null
  else
    #"Converted To Record"
in
  ReturnValue

Your Query
Now, once you've got the "fTextEntryToRecord" query working (and make sure you converted it back into a function if you had to debug it), create a new query with code similar to this:
let
  Source = TextOfYourTextFile,
  #"CRLF to LF" = Text.Replace(Source, "#(cr,lf)", "#(lf)"), // If we can guarantee it's always CRLF or always LF, we don't need this line. Rather than ask, it was easier to take either/or, making the code more robust.
  SplitByBlankLine = Text.Split(#"CRLF to LF", "#(lf,lf)"),
  #"Converted to Records" = List.Transform(
    SplitByBlankLine,
    fTextEntryToRecord
  ),
  #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromRecords(
    List.RemoveNulls(
      #"Converted to Records"
    )
  )
in
  #"Converted to Table"

From there, you'd probably want to change your query to modify the "Age" column to an integer, etc. Up to you.
